# Alternatives to Java applet or solution to unsigned the applet website connection

Tags: java, jsp, applet

I have written an applet that reads data (in the form of string) from some website each 2 seconds, do some processing and then display the results in bar-form (basically display on Swing components). That was working fine when I launched it from netbeans. Once I did it out-side netbeans, all hell break loose because of the signed and un-signed problems, obviously my applet is un-signed.
My question is, what are my other options to do the same process within java ( I am not familiar with the other languages that much) because I have seen people talking about SFX Fx and JSP but I couldnot figure out the mapping from the applet to them. The other thing is: I couldn't find a post that shows how to establish a URL connection from an un-signed applet, are u aware of any?

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There really is no alternative for *cross-site access* in an applet.  The applet needs to be digitally signed.

A JSP could do it without being digitally signed, but then you'd need to be running Java on the server side (an applet needs Java on the client side).

In case you're wondering.  Cross-site access is usually for stealing resource from one site, to reproduce it on another site as if it were the property of the other site.  That is why Sun/Oracle decided the applet need to be digitally signed.  The user should know that they are accepting an applet that requires full permissions (available only after the user is prompted, and clicks OK) before it will run.

Comment: Thx alot. This kind of puts me on the track. I am not very familiar with JSP so I am wondering whether they can display swing components and stuff like that?

Comment: *"..JSP.."* By the time it gets to the browser, it is HTML. *"so I am wondering whether they can display swing components"* No.  That would require an applet.  *"../and stuff like that?"*  If you can find an HTML 5 element as a replacement for it sure. If not, no.